# I want to play a sound based on my ultrason sensor reading

Tags: arduino-nano

The idea is to play the tone that is given by the center value read it by the center ultrasound sensor.

The code that is in Arduino is this one:

```cpp
#include NewPing.h

#define PING_CENTER  2  // Arduino pin tied to both trigger and echo pins on the ultrasonic sensor.
#define PING_RIGHT  3
#define PING_LEFT  4
#define PING_MAX_DISTANCE 200 // Maximum distance we want to ping for (in centimeters). Maximum sensor distance is rated at 400-500cm.
#define buzzerPin = 10


long buzzerFreq1; // The frequency to buzz the buzzer
unsigned int BUZZ_FREQ_MAX = 2500; // Maximum frequency for the buzzer
unsigned int US_MAX = 2023; // Maximum value for ultrason sensor
int c1;

NewPing sonar2(PING_CENTER, PING_CENTER, PING_MAX_DISTANCE); // NewPing setup of pin and maximum distance.
NewPing sonar3(PING_RIGHT, PING_RIGHT, PING_MAX_DISTANCE);
NewPing sonar4(PING_LEFT, PING_LEFT, PING_MAX_DISTANCE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT); // set pin for buzzer output 
}

void loop() { 
  buzzerFreq1 = (center * BUZZ_FREQ_MAX) / US_MAX;
  buzz(buzzerPin,buzzerFreq1,10);
  // tone(buzzerPin, center);
  delay(500);  // Wait 500ms between pings (about 20 pings/sec). 29ms should be the shortest delay between pings.
  unsigned int center = sonar2.ping() / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM; // Send ping, get ping time in microseconds (uS) and convert it to centimeters (cm)
  unsigned int right = sonar3.ping() / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM;
  unsigned int left = sonar4.ping() / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM;
  // Serial.println("Distance: " + String(distanceInCms) + "cm");

  Serial.println(center);
  Serial.println(right);
  Serial.println(left);

}

 // buzz(buzzerPin, buzzerFreq1, 10);
 void buzz(int targetPin, long frequency, long length) {
 // int c1 = center;
  buzzerFreq1 = (center * BUZZ_FREQ_MAX) / US_MAX;
  long delayValue = 1000000/frequency/2;

  int numCycles = frequency * length/1000;

  for (int i=0; i < numCycles; i++){
    digitalWrite(targetPin,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(delayValue);
    digitalWrite(targetPin,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(delayValue);
  }
}
```

And I receive the following error that I have no idea how to solve it.

```
ultrason_onewire_sound.cpp: In function ‘void setup()’:
ultrason_onewire_sound.cpp:26:11: error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token
ultrason_onewire_sound.cpp: In function ‘void loop()’:
ultrason_onewire_sound.cpp:38:8: error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token
ultrason_onewire_sound.cpp: In function ‘void buzz(int, long int, long int)’:
ultrason_onewire_sound.cpp:48:18: error: ‘center’ was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 4):

`#define buzzerPin = 10` shouldn't have an `=` in it.

With the `=` `pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);` will turn into `pinMode(= 10, OUTPUT);` by the pre-processor. Which would give the error, complaining about an `=` token, you got.

Answer (score 0):

You should use arduino built in tone command to play sounds with a buzzer, it will simplify your code and your errors.